# Assigned a value that is never used (simple program)

Tags: unassigned-variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main ()
{
  int numc;
  puts ("NUMBER PLEASE");
  numc=getchar();
  printf ("%d");
  getch ();
  return 0;
}
```

I get the warning numc is assigned a value that is never used, while I'm trying to get the value. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
printf ("%d", numc);
```

?
That would use the value the the compiler is warning you about.

Comment: oh my god I posted this so long ago on my first day of self teaching coding haha... yeah

Answer (score 0):

you never used numc value after assigning.. that's why it is giving warning..

Comment: I never really assigned a value to numc. I'm trying to get the value that the user types.

Comment: numc=getchar(); 
this line actually assign the value which never used further in the program that is why it give warning..

Comment: so How do I get the number from the user by using getchar?